# How to put </textarea> text in a textarea code box

Tags: html, textarea

I am in need of a way to put `<textarea>` (as text) inside a `<textarea>` and then close the textarea inside the text area with a `</textarea>` but doing so, closes the first textarea. It allows the code `<textarea>` inside the textarea though

```
<textarea width=100px>  <!--Text area to appear on screen-->

<title> Test </title>
<textarea placeholder="Hello, Enter your username:">
</textarea>  <!--This bit is supposed to appear inside the text area as text-->

</textarea>  <!--End of the textarea-->
```

I have tried using:

```
<script>
<!--
document.write(unescape("%3C/textarea%3E"));
//-->
</script>
```

instead of `</textarea>` but it doesnt work

Comment: You're looking for HTML encoding which will translate `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape special characters like < > & and " in html:
< = &lt;
> = &gt;
& = &amp;
" =  &quot;

This looks like:

```
<textarea placeholder="Hello, Enter your username:">
&lt;/textarea&gt;

</textarea>  <!--End of the textarea-->
```

If you're using a serverside script/program to render html, almost all languages have escaping functions for html.

Comment: @Japp thanks, got my page working http://sd-storage.weebly.com/encrypt-text.html#axzz3MXgAtvLstack

Comment: Only the less-than character “<” needs to be escaped. (You would need to escape the ampersand “&” too if it were present. There is never any need to escape “"” and “>” in element content.)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: You should always properly HTML encode to ensure your HTML is valid. Also, this can prevent XSS attacks. See [XSS Experimental Minimal Encoding Rules](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Experimental_Minimal_Encoding_Rules).

Comment: @SilverlightFox, “properly” means exactly what I wrote. Consult the HTML specifications (any of them) if you disagree.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: HTML encoding (as per link) will not cause any harm and is at very little cost. It can also aid in identifying XSS flaws in static analysis of code as all output should be passed through your encoding routine and any missing encoding will be easily visible.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela html escape functions typically escape all these characters. quot is important in html attribute context. I'm not sure about gt, in attr context this almost always works, except when the programmer doesn't put quotes around the attribute. escaping gt is a bit safer, but not much.

Comment: Jaap it is safer to escape as old browsers that are not necessarily following standards may get confused and then a malicious user could launch an XSS attack using this flaw. Ie. Your answer is correct from a security point of view too.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<` with its equivalent HTML entity - `&lt;`:

```
<textarea width=100px>
  <!--Text area to appear on screen-->
  <title>Test</title>
  <textarea placeholder="Hello, Enter your username:">
  &lt;/textarea>  <!--This bit is supposed to appear inside the text area as text-->

</textarea><!--End of the textarea-->
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ugmdw3ak/). Do not confuse this with URL encoding (`%nn`), as these are different beasts.